# display some fields in custom post backend

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I am using the following code for the custom post.But i want three fields i.e Location,Persons ,Client to permanently appear in the backend of the custom post rather than having to create and select the custom field our self. I have no idea how to do it. So please help me out.

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'events',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                            'name' => __( 'Events' ),
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Event' ),
                            'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Event' ),
                            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Event' ),
                            'new_item' => __( 'New Event' ),
                            'view' => __( 'View Event' ),
                            'view_item' => __( 'View Event' ),
                            'search_items' => __( 'Search Event' ),
                            'not_found' => __( 'No Event found' ),
                            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Event found in Trash' ),

                            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'events'),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'taxonomies' => array( 'Event type'),
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),

        )
    );
}
```

Comment: This parameter `register_meta_box_cb` lets you add a meta-box to the custom post type by default. You can then write PHP/HTML for that meta-box. Ringing any bells? Plenty of resources out there...

Comment: You could also look at using a pre-existing library such as [Field Manager](http://fieldmanager.org/) or [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to save yourself a ton of work.